# `request.json()` throwing "Response not interpretable as json" using requests

Tags: python, python-requests

```
import requests
import json

def get_movies_from_tastedive(movie):
    d = {"q":movie,"type":"movie","limit":"5"}
    movies = requests.get("https://tastedive.com/api/similar",params=d)
    x = movies.json()
    print(x)
```

I am running the above code trying to access TasteDive API but I keep getting this error:

```
{'error': 'Response not interpretable as json. Try printing the .text attribute'}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Did you try printing the text attribute?

Comment: Please make your title *specific to your individual question*. Almost anyone could write a question with this original ("What is wrong with my code? It keeps giving the same error") title, on almost any topic. As such, it does nothing to inform readers of what the question is actually about.

Comment: the request oes not return a JSON content, this is pretty clear, and as suggested print `movies.text`

Comment: ...if the website *can* return a JSON response, you might need to change the headers on the request to ask it to do so. Check the API documentation for tastedive.com to know.

Comment: I ran the code here using movie='argo' and it didn't give any errors, probably is something with some specific movie, which one did you tried?

Comment: Please also provide the remaining part of your code in order to better understand why you get this error.

Comment: Code looks fine, but could be network issues, or tastedive blocking you. do a movies.raise_for_status(), and you'll probably get more info. Also try printing movies.text.

Answer (score 3):

The endpoint doesn't return JSON.
This probably means that you entered a file name having issues (maybe strange / not accepted characters?).

Please try this code to see what it returns, in my examples it returns always JSON data:

```
import requests
import json

def get_movies_from_tastedive(movie):
    d = {"q":movie,"type":"movie","limit":"5"}
    movies = requests.get("https://tastedive.com/api/similar",params=d)
    try:
        return movies.json()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return movies.text

print("Getting data for movie Seven:")
print(get_movies_from_tastedive("Seven"))
print("\nGetting data for movie Sevssssen:")
print(get_movies_from_tastedive("Sevssssen"))
```

**Output**

```
Getting data for movie Seven:
{u'Similar': {u'Info': [{u'Type': u'movie', u'Name': u'Seven'}], u'Results': [{u'Type': u'movie', u'Name': u'Primal Fear'}, {u'Type': u'movie', u'Name': u'The Usual Suspects'}, {u'Type': u'movie', u'Name': u'The Game'}, {u'Type': u'movie', u'Name': u'Insomnia'}, {u'Type': u'movie', u'Name': u'American History X'}]}}

Getting data for movie Sevssssen:
{u'Similar': {u'Info': [{u'Type': u'unknown', u'Name': u'sevssssen'}, {u'Type': u'unknown', u'Name': u'sevssssen'}], u'Results': []}}
```

Comment: Still not working, it isnt returning anything now, says Keyerror:Similar

Comment: Please let me understand... If you copy and paste this exact code doesn't work for you? It works on my machine...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks very similar to the same I got on [Data Collection and Processing with Python](https://www.coursera.org/learn/data-collection-processing-python/home/welcome) final assignment.

I fixed it using `requests_with_caching` instead of `requests` on Runestone's task

```py
import requests_with_caching

def get_movies_from_tastedive(criteria):
    params = {'q': criteria, 'type': 'movies', 'limit': '5'}
    return requests_with_caching.get('https://tastedive.com/api/similar', params = params).json()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests_with_caching
import json

def get_movies_from_tastedive(name_movie):
    parameters = {'q':name_movie, 'type':'movies', 'limit':5}
    a = requests_with_caching.get( 'https://tastedive.com/api/similar', params = parameters)
    b = a.json()
    return b

print(get_movies_from_tastedive("Bridesmaids"))
print(get_movies_from_tastedive("Black Panther"))
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Output

found in permanent_cache
{'Similar': {'Info': [{'Name': 'Bridesmaids', 'Type': 'movie'}], 'Results': [{'Name': 'Baby Mama', 'Type': 'movie'}, {'Name': 'The Five-Year Engagement', 'Type': 'movie'}, {'Name': 'Bachelorette', 'Type': 'movie'}, {'Name': 'The Heat', 'Type': 'movie'}, {'Name': 'Date Night', 'Type': 'movie'}]}}
found in permanent_cache
{'Similar': {'Info': [{'Name': 'Black Panther', 'Type': 'movie'}], 'Results': [{'Name': 'Captain Marvel', 'Type': 'movie'}, {'Name': 'Avengers: Infinity War', 'Type': 'movie'}, {'Name': 'Ant-Man And The Wasp', 'Type': 'movie'}, {'Name': 'The Fate Of The Furious', 'Type': 'movie'}, {'Name': 'Deadpool 2', 'Type': 'movie'}]}}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain what it is and how/why it solves the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue in Coursera's system (even with `requests_with_caching`) where it worked on my machine. The fix is to change your parameters to reflect proper JSON formatting (i.e. space after each colon and comma):

Your code:

```
d = {"q":movie,"type":"movie","limit":"5"}
```

Proper code which fixed my issue (I had already swapped to requests_with_caching before):

```
d = {"q": movie, "type": "movie", "limit": "5"}
```

After this change my test began miraculously passing.

Answer (score -1):

Actually you are the calling the `API` wrongly. first of all you need to use `data=` or `json=` depending on type of content you are sending to the `API` if it's `form-data` or `JSON`.

Secondly: `movie` is invalid `value` because it's need to be wrapped with `"movie"` < double quotation.

Below you should be able to call the `API` correctly :

```py
import requests
import json

data = {
    "q": "movie",
    "type": "movie",
    "limit": "5"
}


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url, json=data).json()
    print(r)
    #print(r.keys()) # to see the keys as it's now a JSON dict.
    dumper = json.dumps(r, indent=4)
    # print(dumper) #to see it in nice formatted tree.


main("https://tastedive.com/api/similar")
```

Output:

```
{'Similar': {'Info': [{'Name': '!!!', 'Type': 'music'}], 'Results': [{'Name': 'Meeting Of Important People', 'Type': 'music'}, {'Name': 'Soldout', 'Type': 'music'}, {'Name': 'La Tour Montparnasse Infernale', 'Type': 'movie'}, {'Name': 'Young & Sick', 'Type': 'music'}, {'Name': 'The Vanity Project', 'Type': 'music'}, {'Name': 'Tyler Bryant & The Shakedown', 'Type': 'music'}, {'Name': 'Thirsty Fish', 'Type': 'music'}, {'Name': 'Sombear', 'Type': 'music'}, {'Name': 'The High Court', 'Type': 'music'}, {'Name': 'Better Luck Next Time', 'Type': 'music'}, {'Name': 'Stars Of Track And Field', 
'Type': 'music'}, {'Name': 'Beachwood Sparks', 'Type': 'music'}, {'Name': 
'Tinted Windows', 'Type': 'music'}, {'Name': 'Promise Of Redemption', 'Type': 'music'}, {'Name': 'The Music', 'Type': 'music'}, {'Name': 'Pretty Girls Make Graves', 'Type': 'music'}, {'Name': 'Zach Gill', 'Type': 'music'}, {'Name': 'Chappo', 'Type': 'music'}, {'Name': 'Kisses', 'Type': 'music'}, {'Name': 'Jarle Bernhoft', 'Type': 'music'}]}}
```

And for the `dumper`:

```
{
    "Similar": {
        "Info": [
            {
                "Name": "!!!",
                "Type": "music"
            }
        ],
        "Results": [
            {
                "Name": "Meeting Of Important People",
                "Type": "music"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Soldout",
                "Type": "music"
            },
            {
                "Name": "La Tour Montparnasse Infernale",
                "Type": "movie"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Young & Sick",
                "Type": "music"
            },
            {
                "Name": "The Vanity Project",
                "Type": "music"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Tyler Bryant & The Shakedown",
                "Type": "music"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Thirsty Fish",
                "Type": "music"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Sombear",
                "Type": "music"
            },
            {
                "Name": "The High Court",
                "Type": "music"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Better Luck Next Time",
                "Type": "music"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Stars Of Track And Field",
                "Type": "music"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Beachwood Sparks",
                "Type": "music"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Tinted Windows",
                "Type": "music"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Promise Of Redemption",
                "Type": "music"
            },
            {
                "Name": "The Music",
                "Type": "music"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Pretty Girls Make Graves",
                "Type": "music"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Zach Gill",
                "Type": "music"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Chappo",
                "Type": "music"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Kisses",
                "Type": "music"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Jarle Bernhoft",
                "Type": "music"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```